# Map Components not rerendered after navigate back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a page with the following code:

```
 // Homepage
    return (
        <>
            <div>HELLO BE YOu</div>
            {list.map((video) => {
            return <VideoPreview key={video._id} video={video</VideoPreview>
            });}
            {list.map((video) => {
                return <div>TEST</div>
            })}
        </>
    );
```

`VideoPreview` is an imported component:

```
export const VideoPreview = ({video}) => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   function handleClick(){
      navigate('/video');
   }
   return <div onClick={handleClick}>video</div>
}
```

When a user clicks on `<VideoPreview/>`, they will be directed to another page which has been defined in App.js to be

```
    <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path="/video" element={<Videopage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

The bug is that when the user attempts to go back to "/" path from "/video" path, the HomePage component does not render properly.

The items inside the list map do not render. (Other element outside of list.map eg, `<div>HELLO BE YOu</div>` was rendered properly though). I have verified that list is not empty and when i place console.log statements within the map function, those logs gets printed out.

```
{list.map((video) => {
  return <VideoPreview key={video._id} video={video}></VideoPreview>
});}
{list.map((video) => {
  return <div>TEST</div>
})}
```

May i get some help in resolving this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Try to `console.log(list)` in your home component to see what its value is when you go back.

Comment: It is a non empty list.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a Code sandbox? I'll check it out if you.

Comment: Hi, i have the code in a github repository. I've made them public and will keep the setting until this problem is resolved. 

Here is the link to this code with the list: https://github.com/Articulate-Well/App/blob/main/src/Components/VideoGrid/VideoGrid.jsx#L107. You can run 'npm install' and 'npm start' to run the app. 

Apart from this, you will need to start this codebase https://github.com/Articulate-Well/BackendService in the background locally (to receive requests from the app). Since you won't have the credentials to the mongodb connection, you could return a mock list value...